# Should I use pocket holes or I should screw through -I am building an adjustable shelf using 5/8" melamine (96"x20"x12")

Tags: cabinetry

I am building an adjustable shelf 96"x20"x12" (hxwxd) adjacent on both sides to an inside wall corner, anchored to wall
Since this will be kind of tall and slim I will probably install a fixed shelf board in the middle to make it more stable and rigid.

This shelf will will be used to store boxes with smaller tools, larger tools etc etc
It will sit 1" away from each wall because there is electrical conduit on that wall. Since it is at the top I might chose to cut the side panels to allow them to get closer to the wall and eliminate the gap at the back.

As mentioned I will use some furniture anti tip brackets to make sure is is secured

What type of screws can I use to build the frame of the shelf?

Comment: This isn't a type-of-screw query per se, since pocket screws can be any screw (literally, they were done using the same screws as everything else back when the system was first invented..... in the 1800s or slightly earlier!) despite what Kreg would have us believe. What you're asking about instead is pocket screw**ing** versus the convention of screwing in to the horizontal elements through the sides. There are pros and cons to each but at the end of the day this is subjective, since some people will prefer one way — the kind of person who builds everything with their little blue jig [contd]

Comment: ...while others will prefer to go the conventional way (possibly because they'd prefer to put an eye out than buy one of those little blue jigs, the associated overpriced fasteners, oh and the drill bits). ^_^

Comment: I am considering these screws  https://www.rona.ca/en/product/precision-round-head-particle-board-screws-with-washers-zinc-plated-8-dia-x-1-1-4-in-l-1-lb-per-pack-514-756-63868866?viewStore=55140&cq_src=google_ads&cq_cmp=19745635341&cq_con=&cq_term=&cq_med=pla&cq_plac=&cq_net=x&cq_pos=&cq_plt=gp&&cm_mmc=shopping_google-_-19745635341-_--_-&gclid=CjwKCAjwkeqkBhAnEiwA5U-uM_mW1Ys8P_LrmT1Y2HReH7bRcbnXb8HW2Msz3jghEMXfV9348_rhvhoCz2UQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds  I do have the blue thing too already from an older project, my first 10y ago

Comment: Your link is clipped (and I'm not sure if it'll work outside of Canada anyway, many similar links posted recently aren't visible from overseas) but it doesn't matter, your choice of ideal screw will be dependent on which *method* you use. Obviously there are screws suited to Kreg pockets (length being the consideration above all others!) but with conventional screwing you could go with pretty much any countersink-head screw (although certain thread types are better suited to the material), and can go very long indeed if you feel it adds strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use screws designed for use in particle board.

They have a coarse thread and deeper gullets (greater difference between the diameter of the thread and diameter of the shank) to hold better in the grainlessness of particle board.

"Regular" wood screws will work, but they won't hold as well and will be more likely to tear out with movement of the wood. (Not expansion, there's no appreciable amount of expansion in particle board, but with movement of piece against piece, like when you bump into it.)

Comment: While I agree (even though this is MDF) the key thing here is the binary choice, pocket screwing or conventional screwing? That's largely subjective, hence my close vote. A different Q, or actually a couple of them, should be asked and this would be the start of a great Answer to one of them :-)

Comment: Fair point, @Graphus.

Comment: melamine/particleboard screws #8x1 1/2" worked very well. I also predrilled before using the screws